# Update the value of a column with incremental integer value start from 1 in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like below,

```
ID      Name    DisplayOrder
1       abc     2
2       def     5
3       efg     1
4       xyz     3
```

I want update value of DisplayOrder Column like as below,

```
ID      Name    DisplayOrder
1       abc     1
2       def     2
3       efg     3
4       xyz     4
```

What is the mysql query? Help please!

Comment: update `DisplayOrder` perhaps with the primary key value if there are in same order and never deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SET @pos := 0;
UPDATE table SET DisplayOrder = ( SELECT @pos := @pos + 1 ) ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this,

```
SET @myval = 0;
UPDATE table_name SET display_order=(@myval := @myval+1) ;
```